# std::getline alternative when input line endings are mixed

Tags: c++, stdin, stdio, istream, line-endings

I'm trying to read in lines from a `std::istream` but the input may contain `'\r'` **and/or** `'\n'`, so `std::getline` is no use.

Sorry to shout but this seems to need emphasis...

### The input may contain *either* newline type *or both*.

Is there a standard way to do this? At the moment I'm trying

```
char c;
while (in >> c && '\n' != c && '\r' != c)
    out .push_back (c);
```

...but this skips over whitespace. D'oh! `std::noskipws` -- *more* fiddling required and now it's misehaving.

Surely there must be a better way?!?

Comment: Are the delimiters mixed in a single file, or will they just vary between files?

Comment: I know you could probably do it in 1 pass, but I would do 2 passes, one to change all the end of lines (CR, LF, CRLF) to the `std::endl` (using `in.get()` to read the chars instead of the extraction operator), and then use `getline` on the second pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's one way to do it. Basically I've made an implementation of `std::getline` which accepts a predicate instead of a character. This gets you 2/3's of the way there:

```
template <class Ch, class Tr, class A, class Pred>
std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &getline(std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &is, std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, A>& str, Pred p) {

    typename std::string::size_type nread = 0;      
    if(typename std::istream::sentry(is, true)) {
        std::streambuf *sbuf = is.rdbuf();
        str.clear();

        while (nread < str.max_size()) {
            int c1 = sbuf->sbumpc();
            if (Tr::eq_int_type(c1, Tr::eof())) {
                is.setstate(std::istream::eofbit);
                break;
            } else {
                ++nread;
                const Ch ch = Tr::to_char_type(c1);
                if (!p(ch)) {
                    str.push_back(ch);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (nread == 0 || nread >= str.max_size()) {
        is.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
    }

    return is;
}
```

with a functor similar to this:

```
struct is_newline {
    bool operator()(char ch) const {
        return ch == '\n' || ch == '\r';
    }
};
```

Now, the only thing left is to determine if you ended on a `'\r'` or not..., if you did, then if the next character is a `'\n'`, just consume it and ignore it.

**EDIT**: So to put this all into a functional solution, here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace util {

    struct is_newline { 
        bool operator()(char ch) {
            ch_ = ch;
            return ch_ == '\n' || ch_ == '\r';
        }

        char ch_;
    };

    template <class Ch, class Tr, class A, class Pred>
        std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &getline(std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &is, std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, A>& str, Pred &p) {

        typename std::string::size_type nread = 0;

        if(typename std::istream::sentry(is, true)) {
            std::streambuf *const sbuf = is.rdbuf();
                str.clear();

            while (nread < str.max_size()) {
                int c1 = sbuf->sbumpc();
                if (Tr::eq_int_type(c1, Tr::eof())) {
                    is.setstate(std::istream::eofbit);
                    break;
                } else {
                    ++nread;
                    const Ch ch = Tr::to_char_type(c1);
                    if (!p(ch)) {
                        str.push_back(ch);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (nread == 0 || nread >= str.max_size()) {
            is.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
        }

        return is;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::stringstream ss("this\ris a\ntest\r\nyay");
    std::string       item;
    util::is_newline  is_newline;

    while(util::getline(ss, item, is_newline)) {
        if(is_newline.ch_ == '\r' && ss.peek() == '\n') {
            ss.ignore(1);
        }

        std::cout << '[' << item << ']' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've made a couple minor changes to my original example. The `Pred p` parameter is now a reference so that the predicate can store some data (specifically the last `char` tested). And likewise I made the predicate `operator()` non-const so it can store that character.

The in main, I have a string in a `std::stringstream` which has all 3 versions of line breaks. I use my `util::getline`, and if the predicate object says that the last `char` was a `'\r'`, then I `peek()` ahead and ignore `1` character if it happens to be `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. I'm staggered that there isn't a famous one-liner for this!

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to read a line is with `std::getline`.

Edit: If your implementation of `std::getline` is broken, you could write something similar of your own, something like this:

```
std::istream &getline(std::istream &is, std::string &s) { 
    char ch;

    s.clear();

    while (is.get(ch) && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r')
        s += ch;
    return is;
}
```

I should add that technically this probably isn't a matter of `std::getline` being broken, as of the underlying stream implementation being broken -- it's up to the stream to translate from whatever characters signify the end of a line for the platform, into a newline character. Regardless of exactly which parts are broken, however, if your implementation is broken, this may be able to make up for it (then again, if your implementation is broken badly enough, it's hard to be sure this will work either).

Comment: Nope. `getline` can't handle ambiguous delimiters.

Comment: Seems to me that the implementation is aware of the newline character(s) on a particular platform (i.e., standard library functions work fine on Macs, PCs or Linux), otherwise it would be maddening.

Comment: Read the question: the input may contain *either* newline type.

Comment: @spraff: I read the question -- but I also understand how streams (are supposed to) work. In fairness, what it considers the end of a line is implementation defined, but if you're on a platform where either '\r' or '\n' should be treated as the end of a line, then either should be read as a newline (in text/translated mode).

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882:2003 [lib.string.io] defines `getline` as terminiating at a delimiter **single character**, there is no awareness of any such concept as translated mode that I can see. My question could be interpreted as "does any such translated mode exist"?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: one thing to keep in mind is that some file formats (such as the ever evil PDF) allow and often have mixed line endings in them. So it's not just a platform issue :-/.

Comment: @spraff: yes, it exists, but you're looking in the wrong place. As I said, it's a characteristic of the underlying stream. The relevant descriptions of the stream, however, are all given in terms of equivalents to mode strings you'd pass to `fopen`, so you need to look in the C standard (§7.19.2/2 in C99).

Comment: @Evan: Okay, fair enough. I guess PDF fits the old joke about platform independent: it's broken equally on all platforms.

Comment: @Jerry: What about for a `std::stringstream`?

Comment: I even run into .cpp files with mixed lining, because they were edited on different systems and uploaded that way into source control. Visual studio whines about that. Any source that is foreign to platform have risk to have mixed line endings